# Json getting data in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get data from a Json Object in android. I can get it from this url
http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt
but when i try to get it from my site
http://vackle.byethost15.com/mobile/json.txt it won't work.

**This is my code:**

My imports:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView data;
private Button getdata;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button getdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);

    getdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONTask().execute("http://vackle.byethost15.com/moviesDemoItem.txt");
        }

    });


}


public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }


            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String movieName = finalObject.getString("movie");
            int year = finalObject.getInt("year");
            return movieName + " - " + year;


        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return "SHIT";

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            data.setText(result);

        }


    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean from this url http://vackle.byethost15.com/mobile/json.txt?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple - there is no JSON behind your url